# res.send Not Sending Data/Error To Client After Axios Post Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, joi

I am using axios to send form data. After validating server-side however no data/error is being sent back to client.

Here's the client-side axios request:

```
async function postData() {
                const data = {
                    email: d.querySelector("#email").value,
                    pwd: d.querySelector("#pwd").value
                }
               await axios({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "/",
                    data: data,
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    }
                });               
            }
postData()
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("Sent");
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("There was an error:", error);
    });
```

Here's the relevant server-side code (Attention: portion commented "THIS DOESN'T WORK"):

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const { error, value } = schema.validate(req.body);
    if (error) {
        console.log(error); 
        res.send("A server error has occured"); //THIS DOESN'T WORK
    }
    else {
        console.log(value);
        res.send("Successfully posted"); //THIS DOESN'T WORK
    } 
});
```

PS: I am sure this code could be better written but I am just starting out on this journey and any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `no data/error is being sent back to client` or it is just the result of axios request is not actually `return`ed from the `postData` function?

Comment: So I did return the axios request and it worked.. Like so;

return await axios({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "/",
                    data: data,
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    }
                })

Didn't even occur to me at all and I was trying everything else for hours. Thanks 

Comment: Now I have another problem (hopefully the last).. While res.send does log the response in the browser console, I'd like for it to update the actual page, say to display the response object or a string. Any Ideas @SergeySosunov?

Comment: Just set the value of html element with what you need using the same approach you did for getting the values for `data`. You can google that pretty easy.

Comment: Oh ok, that I do know.  It's just I saw a tutorial from about two years ago where res.send just updated the page. Guess I'd just have to do some "heavy lifting". Lol. Thanks again @SergeySosunov 

Comment: Thinking about it, I must have simply missed where they did the aforementioned "heavy lifting" 